# How to change image on hover with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hey guys I'm new here and i'm looking to do something on my website, I have a div and I want that when people hover it with mouse it change the image in it into another image.
I found this http://jsfiddle.net/EXNZr/1/ but it's only working when I hover the image, how do I make it change when I hover the div?
Thanks in advance and sorry for broken english

```
<div id="content"><img id="changeonhover" src="../test/images/yes.png"></div>
```

this is my code, i want that when people hover on "content" the image in "changeonhover" change into no.gif for example

Comment: Do you want it to stay changed?

Comment: What isn't working about that fiddle you posted? It does exactly what you are asking...

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/Ry8E4/

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#theDiv").hover(
        function()
        {
            $("#imgDino").attr("src", "http://www.sitevip.net/gifs/dinosaur/2348_animado.gif");
        },
        function()
        {
            $("#imgDino").attr("src", "http://bestuff.com/images/images_of_stuff/64x64crop/t-rex-51807.jpg?1176587870");
        }                         
    );                  
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/EXNZr/54/

You simply apply the hover event handler to the parent div and change the src of the image tag within using .find();

References:

http://api.jquery.com/find/

Comment: No problem, be sure to click the check box to the left if you feel I best answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#content").hover(
        function()
        {
            $('#changeonhover', this).attr("src", "http://www.sitevip.net/gifs/dinosaur/2348_animado.gif");
        },
        function()
        {
            $('#changeonhover', this).attr("src", "http://bestuff.com/images/images_of_stuff/64x64crop/t-rex-51807.jpg?1176587870");
        }                         
    );                  
});
```

Call event on `#content` and not on `#changehover`.

Answer (score 0):

Feel compelled to tell you this can be done purely with CSS if you change the `<img>` tag to `<div>` with background image

Comment: the bad thing here is when the `src` is provide variable